# How to set up System Link between 2 PS3s?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, networking

I bought a crossover cable a couple days ago.
I read online that you can simply connect 2 ps3s together and setup a LAN Party as long as you had 2 copies of the same game, 2 TVs, and that the game had a LAN feature.

I tried following this guide for it:

**1st ps3** 

1. settings 

2. network settings 

3. connection settings 

4. setup manually 

5. wired connection 

6. enter ip manually 

7. use 1.1.1.0 for ip 

255.255.255.0 for subnet 

2.2.2.4 for dsn 

1.1.1.1 for gateway ip 

8. use auto settings for remainder of the options 

9. enter and test connection settings

**2nd ps3** 

repeat steps 1-6 

1.1.1.1 ip adress 

255.255.255.0 subnet 

2.2.2.4 dsn 

1.1.1.0 gateway ip 

steps 8 & 9 

it will fail and say no network av

**Except the ps3 has:**

IP Address

Subnet Mask

**Default Router

Primary DNS

Secondary DNS**

I tried interchanging the gateway IP for default router and using the dsn for primary DNS and leaving the secondary DNS blank. It didn't work.

Comment: Are both PS3 connected to the same router, and prefereably by the same method (i.e. both wireless, or both wired)?

Comment: The 2 PS3s are connected directly to each other by the crossover cable. I read that it works just for 2 player. But for 3-4 player games a router is needed.

Comment: Ah, I don't have experience doing it without a router in between. If I had to guess they should have the same value for gateway IP (1.1.1.1),

Comment: Damn, It's still a no go and I don't have a spare router on hand.

Comment: I was able to get my hands on a switch but I still don't know how to get the 2 PS3s to talk to each other.